# Как получить время в Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Здравствуйте, пишу в линуксе программу на с++ и столкнулся с проблемой...
Не могу найти функцию которая возвращает текущее время в виде строки.... Например такой:
Min Sec Day Month Year. Порядок не важен... Помогите с функцией.
Спасибо.

Comment: Точно так же, как, собственно, и в Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
char output[20];
time_t seconds = time(NULL);
tm* timeinfo = localtime(&seconds);
strcpy(output," Date:  "); 
strcat(output,asctime(timeinfo));
//Содержание output таким образом "Date:  Wed Sep 19 23:09:59 2012"
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!

Comment: strcat(output," Date:  "); 

Очень плохо. Надо здесь либо strcpy, либо sprintf использовать. Со strcat результат будет непредсказуемым!

Comment: Да это верное замечание, исправил.